# Reuse a previously processed value in a column

Tags: sql, case, reusability

I hope someone can help me on that as I'm struggling to get it work as expected.

In my DB I have phone numbers with different format (i.e: 15551234, 5551234, +15551234).
So I'm using the following CASE to clean this up and it works great:

```
CASE
LEFT(DC.PhoneNumber0,1)  
WHEN '+' then replace(DC.PhoneNumber0,'+1','')
WHEN 1 then right(DC.PhoneNumber0,len(DC.PhoneNumber0)-1)
ELSE DC.PhoneNumber0
End 'Transformed Number',
```

Now this return the clean phone number I need to work on (5551234) in the 'Transformed column'

I would like now to use another CASE that retrieve this cleaned number and extract the area code to translate it in an understandable value (i.e.: 201 => US - New Jersey)

So I'm stuck in writing the second CASE.
I tried something like that, but it's NOT working with numbers that are already clean in my DB.

```
CASE
WHEN right(left(replace(DC.PhoneNumber0,'+',''),4),3) in (201, 1201) then 'US - New Jersey'
WHEN right(left(replace(DC.PhoneNumber0,'+',''),4),3) in (202, 1202) then 'US - Washington D.C.'
```

Ideally, I would like to reuse, the value that I just transformed in the previous CASE. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: which sql database and version?

Comment: show your transformed data and desired output... at the moment I can't see 201 and 1021 from your data, will be hard to read if you are not from the US

Comment: It's SQL 2012 used with SCCM 2012 SP1.

Comment: transformed data is like this:
OriginalPhoneNumber  TransformedPhoneNumber
+17801234567   7801234567
16151234567           6151234567
8101234567           8101234567

Answer (score 0):

You can CREATE FUNCTION containing your initial phone number parse logic and then just reference the function twice. Your DBMS create function syntax should have a clause declaring the function to be NOT VARIANT or DETERMINISTIC so it can be run only once per row regardless how many times you invoke it.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about this, but I'm not skilled enough in SQL to do that. Could you please give me some tips?